# Can't get the position of item of dynamically created spinner

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, spinner, android-spinner

Basically i have a method `createList()` which creates a Spinner and then i add those spinners to an arrayList `myList`. After adding them i use `setOnItemSelectedListener` on each Spinner in the array List to get the position but no matter what i select in a spinner i get the position 0. Interestingly, if i don't add spinners to ArrayList and use only one spinner i get the position easily. The problem arises when i put spinner objects in an arrayList.

Here is the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    Spinner spinner1;
    int pos;
    ArrayList<Spinner> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    int length = 0;
    int[] numbers;
    int show;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.root);
    }

    public void showPosition(View view) {
        numbers = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            myList.get(i).setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    numbers[i] = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void createList(View view) {
        length++;
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.city, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner1 = new Spinner(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 50);
        spinner1.setLayoutParams(params);
        spinner1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        myList.add(spinner1);
        linearLayout.addView(spinner1);

    }

}
```

When i print `number` in the log all the elements of this array are zero no matter what item i have selected in the spinner.

Please help stuck on it for few days :(

Comment: You intialize length equals 0 and make it as paramater in loop. When you execute loop, looping program will end at first loop and make number[i] = 0 since you dont call createList function

Comment: my variable "length" does have a value . It is not zero but the number of times createList is executed. I have checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

Directly get the position by `mySpinner.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition()` and use that position with a switch statement to make it workable.